# safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding

Tags: javascript, c#, ios, asp.net, safari

I have one page which takes some time to load in asp.net website. It works with all Android OS, all MAC OS, all iOS **except iOS with version 10.0.0.2 with safari browser**

When I am trying to load same page with safari in iOS 10.0.0.2, it throws **'safari could not open the page because the server stopped responding'.**

I know the reason for this error is, my page is taking time. But my page is already optimized and it has so many things, that's why it is taking time.
I want to prevent my page from this error in 10.0.0.2. 
I tried all the possible ways to solve this issue like :

1. Clear cookie and browsing data
2. Added 8.8.8.8 to DNS server
3. Airplane mode on-off
4. iPhone restart

But nothing helps.

Please help me to figure out this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found that iOS 10.0.0.2 has default timeout approx 1 minute. My page was taking more than 1 minute to load. That's why safari assumed that server is not responding and it was throwing that message.

I did not get any setting or anything to extend timeout limit of safari. At the end I optimized my code.

I am using **telerik rad grid** in my page and its MasterTableView's property named **'HierarchyLoadMode' was set as 'client'. I changed it to 'ServerOnDemand'.**

That solved my issue by reducing page load time.
As
 
**1) 'Client' loads grid data at the time of page load. 

2) 'ServerOnDemand' loads grid data at the time of grid expanding**

My page load time has been reduced and safari stopped throwing message.

If you are using telerik rad grid, I hope this will help you.